# Configuring interceptor in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

I am using Spring 3.0

I need to write an interceptor which intercepts all urls. in my application

I wrote one intercptor

```
public class HelloInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
```

how can i configure it in  spring-servlet.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Using `<mvc:interceptors>` (see [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors)), e.g.

> An example of registering an interceptor applied to all URL paths:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="x.y.HelloInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I am using tiles and I do not believe the normal xml interceptor markup works.  This seems to work.  Thanks!